# GCP Storage Usage Logs writing in multiple buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am interested, is it possible to write logs in 2 buckets?

I didn't find any information about this in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs).
For single bucket I use this command:

```
gsutil logging set on -b gs://example-logs-bucket [-o log_object_prefix ] gs://example-bucket
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you have a look to log sink and router?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
Yes, but they are for another type of logs and for logging buckets.
I need to collect Storage Usage Logs from 1 bucket to another 2-3 buckets.
I didn’t find in the documentation how to do this, but I also didn’t find that it can’t be done :)

Comment: Ah..... obviously, you can't. It's a legacy feature.